# Synergy server and client on single machine loop?

Tags: synergy

I have already seen:

- [Is it possible to set up a screen loop in synergy 1.4? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/386664/is-it-possible-to-set-up-a-screen-loop-in-synergy-1-4)
- [tunnel - How to run both a Synergy Client and a Synergy Server on the same machine? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/213413/how-to-run-both-a-synergy-client-and-a-synergy-server-on-the-same-machine)

... but none of them answers my question, which is a bit theoretical.

Namely, I'd like to set up a synergy server and client on a single machine, such that moving the mouse, causes the server (which is my machine) to propagate the data to the client (which is the same machine) - which would eventually enable a mouse motion, but a guess with a delay. As a note, I'm on an Ubuntu OS.

I have tried using this conf file (`mysyn.conf`):

```
section: screens
    mypc:
end
section: links
    ljutfraer:
        left = mypc
        right = mypc
end
```

(*note: using `127.0.0.1` instead of the computer name `mypc` in the .conf, results with `FATAL: synergys.cpp,655: unknown screen name 'mypc'`*)

Then I run the server, in one terminal, with:

```
synergys -d DEBUG -f --config ./mysyn.conf
```

... and I run the client, in another terminal, with:

```
synergyc -d DEBUG -f 127.0.0.1
```

... which results with the error:

```
ERROR: CServerProxy.cpp,182: server already has a connected client with name "mypc"
WARNING: synergyc.cpp,265: failed to connect to server: server already has a connected client with our name
DEBUG: synergyc.cpp,237: retry in 1 seconds
ERROR: CServerProxy.cpp,182: server already has a connected client with name "mypc"
WARNING: synergyc.cpp,265: failed to connect to server: server already has a connected client with our name
DEBUG: synergyc.cpp,237: retry in 3 seconds
```

So, is there a way to set up `synergy` client and server such that they run on the same machine - resulting with nothing else but a delay in mouse movement?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Easy you only run the server side, you don't need the client and this is evident in the error in the logs.

```
server already has a connected client with name "mypc"
```

If you are trying to switch between Ubuntu and a Virtual Machine (say windows xp) you need to setup a virtual network connection between host and guest os, with server running on ubuntu and client on the guest os.

When you run the server it contains the necessary code to loop one side of the screen to the other.

here is my config using just one os (windows xp) and wrapping sides left <--> Right.

```
    section: screens
    mypc:
        halfDuplexCapsLock = false
        halfDuplexNumLock = false
        halfDuplexScrollLock = false
        xtestIsXineramaUnaware = false
        switchCorners = none 
        switchCornerSize = 0
end

section: aliases
end

section: links
    mypc:
        right = mypc
        left  = mypc
end

section: options
    relativeMouseMoves = false
    screenSaverSync = true
    win32KeepForeground = false
    switchCorners = none 
    switchCornerSize = 0
end
```

It uses no client program to achieve this just the server looping it's self.